# Activiti V6.0 DB queries causing some max spikes of CPU in production environment

Tags: activiti

Please take a look at the below findings. In summary, the problem is in the query itself due to the datatypes that are defined in the ACTIVITI V6.0 tables.

The following tests were conducted on ACTIVITI V6.0 DB
Existing query took 9 minutes 53 seconds with (50 eDTUs)!

```
select *
from ACT_RU_VARIABLE
where EXECUTION_ID_ = 10000074
and NAME_= 'abccd'
and TASK_ID_ is null;
```

New query took 3 milliseconds with (50 eDTUs)! No index was created.

```
select *
from ACT_RU_VARIABLE
where EXECUTION_ID_ = '10000074'
and NAME_= 'abccd'
and TASK_ID_ is null;
```

Since the DB tables and queries are managed by Activiti itself, Can you guys please suggest how should be address this?

We thought of changing the datatype but we are not sure how this is going to impact on functional Activiti workflows, so wanted to have your insights as well on it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm really not sure I understand your problem.
The Activiti schema for V6 is controlled by the Mybatis ORM.
And the schema create script here: https://github.com/Activiti/Activiti/blob/6.x/modules/activiti-engine/src/main/resources/org/activiti/db/create/activiti.mysql.create.engine.sql
Explicitly indicates the EXECUTION_ID_ field is a Varchar.

```
create table ACT_RU_VARIABLE (
    ID_ varchar(64) not null,
    REV_ integer,
    TYPE_ varchar(255) not null,
    NAME_ varchar(255) not null,
    EXECUTION_ID_ varchar(64),
    PROC_INST_ID_ varchar(64),
    TASK_ID_ varchar(64),
    BYTEARRAY_ID_ varchar(64),
    DOUBLE_ double,
    LONG_ bigint,
    TEXT_ varchar(4000),
    TEXT2_ varchar(4000),
    primary key (ID_)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;
```

The MyBatis mappings for the Variable instances are here:

https://github.com/Activiti/Activiti/blob/6.x/modules/activiti-engine/src/main/resources/org/activiti/db/mapping/entity/VariableInstance.xml

And again, the queries are using strings.

So, why would you be querying against the EXECUTION_ID_ using anything other than a string?

As for how to handle it, the beauty of using an ORM like Mybatis is that it is relatively easy to change or extend the schema.
All you need to do is update the appropriate mapping.xml, crate/drop script and the associated Entity.